# Bubbling up events to be subscribed to

Tags: c#, wcf, events

I have a class `ChatManager`, which has a `ChatServer` and a `ChatClient`(WCF) class inside of them.

I want my controller which instantiates the `ChatManager` to be able to subscribe to the `UserConnected`, `UserDisconnected` and `MessageReceived` events that are on the `ChatClient`.

What is the most elegant and logical way to do this? Is it silly for me to define the events in the `ChatClient` like I have, and then redefine the events in the `ChatManager` solely to pass the events up to the Controller without it having to deal with or know about the `ChatClient`? The `ChatManager` would subscribe to the events of the `ChatClient`, and then fire off its own events which the `ChatController` would be listening to.

I know WPF has the concept of bubbling up of events, but I don't know if that is for this type of scenario, since nothing is part of a user interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start by questioning whether both `ChatManager` and `ChatController` can both justify their own existence. Generally whenever you find yourself creating a "Manager" class, it really isn't necessary, especially if part of what it is doing consists of merely relaying messages.

Controller classes can struggle against SRP since their "responsibility" is quite broad. In cases where you want to delegate responsibility for certain behaviour then leave the responsibility for the `ChatClient` with the controller, and initialize a subordinate controller with the `ChatClient` (through a contract interface) so that it can interact with the client as needed. Just make sure that when you start registering for events that you de-register those events before discarding subordinates or the client, otherwise you'll be looking at managed memory leaks.

Comment: Steve, I think you might be right about the justification of existence of both of them. Originally I had all the server code and all the client code in the manager class itself. I then recently refactored all of it out into the two separate classes, and the manager is merely a means to start the server and join servers by instantiating the server and client.

I think it is the best move to just get rid of the `ChatManager` now and have the controller do all of that. Though I do wonder if it will make the controller too bloated. But, I guess that logically falls into its responsibilities.

Answer (score 1):

It is not bubbling events you are looking for. You can easily subscribe to these events by calling an instance of the child class in your parent (ChatManager) and subscribing to the Events like so :

```
chatManager.UserConnected += (param1, param2) => {
    //your code here
};
```

Comment: Wiring events with anonymous delegates is an excellent way to end up with instances that won't be garbage collected.

Comment: Agreed. This is just a basic implementation. There are more elegant ways to handle such things.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a need for an event to only conditionally reach the things that would subscribe to it (or to be processed sequentially by multiple handlers), "bubbling" isn't really something you should need. Using an [event aggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx) would probably be the best way to go.

Comment: Well, I am using Prism, which has an event aggregator. Does it make sense to create a dependency in the model for event aggregation? Right now my ChatManager knows nothing about Prism.

Comment: @Cowman It depends on a couple factors I would think. 1) Is there ever a place where the library containing ChatManager would be used without using Prism 2) Is there a way to make the dependency weak (ie. using only an interface to the event aggregator in ChatManager and having something fulfill the dependency for it)